# How to move up frames after calling stacktrace or browser

Tags: r, rstudio

In rstudio, after an error, the stack trace is displayed on the right.

`traceback()` also returns the stack trace, as well as `where` while in the browser, which is now invoked.

On the top right under `Environment` it displays the environment corresponding to the frame that one is under with rstudio - that is, on the right one can click on different lines in the `traceback` and see on the top the value for the arguments and so on. rstudio even jumps to the correct function. So far so good.

However, one cannot execute any of the statements in those functions because the browser session itself is still much deeper. So one would need to move the browser up the stack trace.

But how do I do that? `n`, `s`, `f` all exit the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Use `recover()`. It will display the list of stack frames and allow you to choose one in to place the browser.

If you're not already using the [preview release of RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/), you might give it a try for this task; it includes some minor improvements to the way call frames synchronize with the browser (i.e. selecting a frame with `recover()` will highlight the correct stack frame in RStudio, which doesn't work in the current stable build).